# Bootstrap 4 invalid-tooltip not being used

Tags: php, forms, validation, bootstrap-4

I'm attempting to use the Bootstrap 4 validation tools described [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/forms/#tooltips). The validation *does* appear to properly detect an input left empty or an email that is not valid, but it is not using the customized invalid-tooltip that I have specified in my markup for the textarea.

Here's my form:

```html
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
        <h2 class="card-title">Email</h2>
        <form class="needs-validation" action="/contact/form-submit" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="name@example.com" required>
                <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We need this to respond. It will not be stored by this website.</small>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div>
                <label for="messageTextarea">Email message</label>
                <textarea name="message" class="form-control" id="messageTextarea" rows="3" required></textarea>
                <div class="invalid-tooltip">
                    Please provide a message.
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can see that I've specified a div with `class="invalid-tooltip"` in my form but it does not get used. If you attempt to submit the form while leaving the **messageTexarea** textarea empty, the tooltip displayed says "Please fill out this field." instead of "Please provide a message."

Have I overlooked something? The documentation is not very informative about what sort of markup you need to get this working.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding 'novalidate' to your form tag to avoid HTML5 validation check.

```
<form class="needs-validation" action="/contact/form-submit" method="post" novalidate>
```